# Java program using arrays created by data entry

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to create a small java program where the user will enter a string of numbers such as `2 4 6 7 8 9 0 3 4 5`.  These numbers will be saved to an array of `int[]` type. I then need the program to calculate how many of each number has been entered and output 2 columns, one containing the number entered and the other containing the amount of times the individual number was entered.  Using the above numbers, I need the output to be as below:

```
Number    Times Entered
2             1
4             2
6             1
7             1
8             1
9             1
0             1
3             1
5             1
```

So far I am using 3 classes.  An application class that contains the main method, a driver class and the class containing the logic and objects.  At this stage I have only started work on the class containing the logic.  The code I have so far is below:

```
package arrayentry;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Entry {

    private Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);  
    private int[] count = new int[51];


    public void countNumberEntry(int[] countArray){
    int input = scn.nextInt();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    if (input == i)
        count[i]++;
    }

    public void dataEntry(){
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers between 1 and 50");
        count = scn.nextInt[]();
    }
  }
```

Any ideas as to how I can get this to work would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me up the wall.

Thanks.

EDIT:  To elaborate, I am have issues with everything.  I for some reason can't get my head around it.  I have read books etc but I can't get it.  I need to store the entered numbers into an array of 50, then calculate the amount of times each number is entered and output as above.

To be honest I am just trying to get a grip / start on this.

Comment: Please give us more information on just what is holding you up, just where your stuck. As presented this looks less like a question and more like a work order.

Answer (score 1):

This would actually be easier with a HashMap. Every time you read a number, check to see if it's in the map. If it is, increment the count, otherwise, insert it with a count of 1.

Since this assignment requires arrays, you'll want to create 2 50-cell arrays. In 1, store the value of the number read, in the second, store the count. Put both values in the cell that corresponds with the number read. Then just print off the values you need.

```
package arrayentry;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Entry {

    private Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);  
    private int[] numbers = new int[51];
    private int[] count = new int[51];

    public Entry() {
        // All counts start at 0, all numbers start at -1 (invalid, so we know it's not from user input)
        for (int cell = 0; cell < count.length; cell++) {
            count[cell] = 0;
            values[cell] = -1;
        }
    }

    public void dataEntry(){
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers between 1 and 50");
        int[] input = scn.nextInt[]();

        for (int value : input) {
            numbers[value] = value;
            counts[value] += 1;
        }
    }

    public void printCounts() {
        System.out.println("Number\tTimes Encountered.");
        for (int cell = 0; cell < numbers.length; cell++) {
            // Don't print counts of any number we didn't see in the input.
            if (numbers[cell] > 0) {
                System.out.println(numbers[cell] + "\t" + counts[cell]);
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Probably would, but the exercise requires the use of an array (self learning exercise, not homework).

Answer (score 1):

You can create another array that will store number of occurences for you

```
   public int [] countOccurences(int originalArray[]){    
        int countedOccurencesArray[]= new int [51];
            for(int i=0;i<originalArray.length){
            contedOccurencesArray[originalArray[i]]++;
            }

    return countedOccurences;}
```

Comment: This looks like a good idea.  How would I implement both arrays in the same class?

Comment: i dont know if i unterstand you question correctly but my answer should be clear enough. You just declare both arrays in for example main class and then fill them with implemented methods(method for filling array by user, and method for counting occurences of numbers). I cant be any more specific